# What makes a sentence complete in the English language?

Tags: past-simple

Is the following a complete sentence :

> I played soccer with my friends

In my language which is Arabic, it's a fully meaningful sentence. Is it the same in English?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Arabic, but in English, if it has a subject and a "predicate" (meaning a "verb"), it is a complete sentence.

The subject is "**I**". The verb is "**played**" (in the past tense). So yes, that is a complete sentence, and it should end with a period (or "full stop", as some people call it.)

Comment: So mentioning a specific time is not important to make a full sentence , But it's **more important** when the sentence is a standalone sentence to make some sense to the listener. Is that right ?

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef If I saw this sentence in isolation I'd think “Why are you telling me this?” – but that's true of many complete sentences!  I'd be surprised if you can write a sentence that cries out for context in one language but not another.